# Is Rails 5 support all gems from rails 4? what if we need to use that has not been upgraded for rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, upgrade

I have a meaning to make a rails application in rails 5 but i am confused which one should i need to go, rails 4 or rails 5. Rails 5 support good feature like web sockets but what about those gem that has not been supported for rails 5. how to tackle that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 5 was released on June 30, 2016 (and it was in beta/rc for a good while before that). That's a good amount of time for maintainers of all active gems to update them. If a gem is not updated to support rails 5, it is likely to not be very well supported in general, and you'll be better off getting rid of it or picking another, more maintained alternative.

Comment: what about this statistics on this sites http://www.ready4rails.net  they have mention only 66 ready for rails 5 and 965 are unknown and 7 in not ready

Comment: @WaleedArshad That list cannot possibly be up-to-date, `redis-rails` is working great for me on Rails 5.1 for example.

Comment: @WaleedArshad: yep, redis-rails [does support rails 5](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails/blob/babbe65e876e16f5ebaab21e953ba9ba65889cd0/redis-rails.gemspec#L23-L24)